# Wrong logic? Program isn't working like it I want it to

Tags: c, c89

*Im using C89*

I am writing a small program for practice and I thought the logic I used is correct, yet it is printing different results than what I want.

My program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct animal 
{   
    char species[30]; 
    char breed[30];   };

void addAnimal( struct animal unique[], int *count, char* newspecies, char* newbreed);

int main(void)
{

   struct animal unique[10] = { {"Cat", "Persian"}, {"Dog", "Collie"},
                                {"Bird", "Conure"}, {"Dog", "Lab"} };
   int i;
   int count = 4;

   addAnimal(unique, &count, "Cat", "Calico");
   addAnimal(unique, &count, "Bird", "Budgie");
   addAnimal(unique, &count, "Dog", "Lab");

   for( i = 0; i < count+1; i++)
       printf("%s, %s\n", unique[i].species, unique[i].breed);
}
```

And I have this function:

```
void addAnimal( struct animal unique[], int *count, char* newspecies, char* newbreed)
{

    int i, k = 0;
    k = *count;

    for( i = 0; i < k; i ++)
    {
       if( strcmp(unique[i].species, newspecies) && strcmp(unique[i].breed, newbreed) )
       {
          printf("both match\n");
          /* do nothing */
       }
       else
       {
          *count = *count + 1;
          strcpy(unique[*count]. species, newspecies);
          strcpy(unique[*count]. breed, newbreed);
       }
    }
}
```

Basically I want the function to add the given names if they do not exist already, and do nothing is they do exist.

What I keep getting (without all the extra print statements) is

```
Cat, Persian
Dog, Collie
Bird, Conure
Dog, Lab
, 
Cat, Calico
Bird, Budgie
Dog, Lab
```

which is wrong. And I have no idea why that comma is printing either.

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to see what is happening.

Comment: `strcmp` returns `0` when the strings are equal; you’re checking that they’re not equal. Is that intentional? You should also check all of them before deciding to add, and break when there’s a match.

Comment: @false Yes if they are not equal I want to add the values that I am passing through the function, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
void addAnimal( struct animal unique[], int *count, char* newspecies, char* newbreed){
    int i, k = *count;

    for( i = 0; i < k; i++){
       if( strcmp(unique[i].species, newspecies)==0 && strcmp(unique[i].breed, newbreed)==0 ){
          printf("both match\n");
          return ;
       }
    }
    //added only once (Rather than if it does not match the data for each)
    strcpy(unique[*count].species, newspecies);
    strcpy(unique[*count].breed, newbreed);
    *count = *count + 1;
}
```

and at main

```
   for( i = 0; i < count; i++)
       printf("%s, %s\n", unique[i].species, unique[i].breed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the function the following way

```
void addAnimal( struct animal unique[], int *count, const char *newspecies, const char *newbreed);

void addAnimal( struct animal unique[], int *count, const char *newspecies, const char *newbreed)
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < *count && 
            ( strcmp( unique[i].species, newspecies ) || strcmp( unique[i].breed, newbreed ) ) i++; 

    if ( i == *count )
    {
          strcpy( unique[*count].species, newspecies );
          strcpy( unique[*count].breed, newbreed );
          ++*count;
    }
    else
    {
          printf( "both match\n" );
    }
}
```

And change the loop in main the following way

```
   for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
       printf( "%s, %s\n", unique[i].species, unique[i].breed );
```